A "factorial fraction" which is an integer
We know that if $a,b,...,l$ are positive integers totaling $n$, then the fraction $$\frac {n!}{a!b!...l!}$$ is an integer. This could be shown by using the inequality $[x_1+x_2+...+x_n] \geq [x_1]+...+[x_n]$ and the formula of the greatest power of a prime number in the standard decomposiotion of a positive integer into prime powers.
Now, if the integers $a,b,...,l$ have no common dovisors and sum to $n$, I want to find a proof of the fact that, in this case, the fraction $$\frac {(n-1)!}{a!b!...l!}$$ is also an integer. Incidentally, I know that this integer is the number of different placings of $ n$ objects on a circle with the assumption that these $n$ objects are subdivided into groups so that in the first group $a$ of them are of type $A$, in the second group $b$ of them are of type $B$, ..., and in the final group $l$ objects are of type $L$.
I would be thankful for any help or suggestion.

Are you assuming that you have more than one integer in the denominator?  If not, taking $a=n$, for some prime $n$, is a counterexample.

$\frac{(n-1)!}N={(a-1)!b!\cdots \ell!}$ is an integer. So $a\mid nN,$ so if $\gcd(a,n)=1,$ then $a\mid N,$ giving your result. So the only counterexamples are when $\gcd(a,n)\neq 1$ and $\gcd(b,n)\neq 1,$ and ... Prove that isn't possible.

@lulu Yes, there are more than one integer in the denominator.

A combinatorial proof of your last claim is, of course, also a proof that your fraction is an integer.

Let $a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_K$ be a sequence of $K \geq 2$ positive integers, corresponding to your $a,\ldots,l$, such that $\operatorname{gcd}(a_1,\ldots,a_K) = 1$. We define $n = \sum_{i=1}^K a_i$. We want to show
$$ X = \frac{(n-1)!}{\prod_{i=1}^K a_i!} $$
is an integer.
Here's a tool letting us look at factors one prime at a time:
For a prime $p$ and a non-zero rational number $x$, define $\nu_p(r)$ to be the smallest integer $m$ such that for some integer $y$ not divisible by $p$, $p^m y$ is an integer. In other words, $\nu_p(r)$ are the possibly-negative powers involved in the unique prime factorization of $r$:
$$ r = 2^{\nu_2(r)} 3^{\nu_3(r)} 5^{\nu_3(r)} \cdots = \prod_{p\textrm{ prime}} p^{\nu_p(r)} $$
(This converges, or can be considered a finite product, since for all but a finite set of $p$, $\nu_p(r)=0$ and $p^{\nu_p(r)}=1$.)
Note $r$ is an integer if and only if $\nu_p(r) \geq 0$ for every prime $p$.
Since we can show that $\nu_p(xy) = \nu_p(x) + \nu_p(y)$ for every non-zero rational $x$ and $y$, we have for every prime $p$,
$$ \nu_p(X) = \nu_p((n-1)!) - \sum_{i=1}^K \nu_p(a_i!) $$
For every prime $p$, since $\gcd(a_1,\ldots,a_K)=1$ there is at least one $a_i$ not divisible by $p$, and $\nu_p(a_i)=0$. So omitting them from the sum above doesn't change the result:
$$ \nu_p(X) = \nu_p((n-1)!) - \sum_{\substack{1\leq i \leq K \\ \nu_p(a_i) \neq 0}} \nu_p(a_i!) $$
But now this subsequence of $(a_i)$ must sum to less than $n$, since at least one positive integer was removed:
$$ \sum_{\substack{1 \leq i \leq K \\ \nu_p(a_i) \neq 0}} a_i = m \leq n-1 $$
By the fact at the start of the question post,
$$ Y_p = \frac{m!}{\displaystyle \prod_{\substack{1 \leq i \leq K \\ \nu_p(a_i) \neq 0}} a_i!} $$
is an integer, so
$$ \nu_p(Y_p) = \nu_p(m!) - \sum_{\substack{1 \leq i \leq K \\ \nu_p(a_i) \neq 0}} \nu_p(a_i!) \geq 0 $$
And since $\frac{(n-1)!}{m!}$ is an integer,
$$ \nu_p\left(\frac{(n-1)!}{m!}\right) \geq 0 $$
$$ \nu_p(X) = \nu_p\left(\frac{(n-1)!}{m!}\right) + \nu_p(Y) \geq 0 $$
Finally, since $\nu_p(X) \geq 0$ for every prime $p$, $X$ is an integer.
